# problemas al mostrar una imagen en una tabla php con SQL

Tags: php

Buenas tengo un problema con querer mostrar imágenes en una tabla.

Este es mi codigo

```
<?php
    $servername = "***";
    $username = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $dbname = "registrodatos";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }

    $salida = "";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM registrodatos WHERE Name NOT LIKE '' ORDER By Id_no LIMIT 25";




    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM registrodatos WHERE nombres LIKE '%$q%' OR apellidos LIKE '%$q%' OR documento LIKE '%$q%' OR nombredecontac LIKE '%$q%' OR telefono LIKE '$q' ";
    }


     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   $resultado = $conn->query($query);
   ////------------------------

  ///-----------------  
    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
        $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                <thead>
                    <tr id='titulo'>
                        <td>Nombres</td>
                        <td>Apellido</td>
                        <td>Tipo de Documento</td>
                        <td>Numero de Documento</td>
                        <td>Numero de Registro</td>
                        <td>Horas</td>
                        <td>Nombre de contacto</td>
                        <td>Telefono</td>
                        <td>Foto de usuario</td>
                        </tr>

                </thead>


        <tbody>";

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc())


        {
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['nombres']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['apellidos']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['estado_civil']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['documento']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['registro']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['ubigeo']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['nombredecontac']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>

///------- Lo que deseo es que acá me muestre la imagen y no la ruta de la imagen que esta almacenada en el SQL.-------------
                         <td>".$fila['fotos']."</td>
///----------------la imagen esta guardada en el SQL type   longblob.-----





                    </tr>";

    }
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        $salida.="NO HAY DATOS :(";
    }


    echo $salida;

    $conn->close();



?>
```

Comment: Donde se guarda la imagen, en algún directorio, donde? Si la ruta no fue guardada tiene que indicarla `<td>"ruta/.$fila['fotos']."</td>`

Comment: buenas la carpeta se llama images lo que me muestra la tabla al hacer la consulta es images/46837107_599208747200835_4733053277292199936_n.jpg lo que deseo es que me muestre la imagen el buscador y no su ruta

Comment: De a cuerdo con Victor Hugo Tirado, solo debes agregar una etiqueta <img> dentro de la etiqueta <td>, prueba y nos cuentas como te va <td><img src=".$fila['fotos']."></td>

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del td deberías usar la etiqueta img. Esta es la que visualiza tu imagen:

```
<td><img src=".$fila['fotos']." ></td>
```

Lo que se almacena en esa variable es la ruta, esa ruta debería ir en el atributo src de la etiqueta img. Luego depende de vos el tamaño y el estilo que quieras darle dentro de tu tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: No cerrar la etiqueta con algún instructor podría provocar en algunos casos error en el código HTML. Esto debería ser `<img src="..." />` o  `<img src="..." ></img>`